# How to make my own edit after I rejected an suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edits

When I view a question, sometimes I want to edit it. But if someone already suggested an edit to this question, click the edit link will ask me to review the edit. But this time the edit is bad so I rejected it. I then want to make my own edit but found the edit link direct me to the review page again without give me any other options.

What can I do? What until it is been approved/rejected then make my own edit?

Is anyway that I can make the edit regardless someone suggested something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you outright reject a suggested edit then you can't do anything further until that edit has reached the threshold to be accepted or rejected.

I wouldn't be too concerned about this flow - it's not common to need to reject and then instantly apply your own edit.

If you think you'll get into this situation again then click *Improve*:

[image]

and make sure you deselect the *Suggested edit was helpful* checkbox:

[image]

Comment: If I rejected something, I still wish to make an unrelated edit to the post. I don't really want to _improve_ that edit. I want to make my change without anything from that edit.

Comment: @BryanChen I understand that, but improving the current suggestion is the only way to effect your edit immediately - otherwise you have to wait for the question to leave the queue. Basically you have to wait your turn unless you are willing to directly intervene by improving.

Comment: @BryanChen: If you want to start afresh, you can go to `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/ID/revisions` (get the ID from the title link before you click "improve"), you can then click "source" of the latest revision, and copy it into the "improve" editor. Bit of a faff, I'll admit; but it's your only way, and once you get into the habit of it (I do it quite a bit), it's not too bad.

Answer (score 5):

You *can* now reject an edit and immediately apply your own edit thanks to the "Reject and Edit" button:

[image]